# Get ID of last inserted element

Tags: mysql, database, node.js

Basically I have two table

```
User -> id, name , email , fname, lname etc...

Device -> id, name, user_id, etc......
```

here first I will insert data into User table and I get result,
from that result how to get the Id of the User table entry so that I can use is as `user_id` for the entry in device 
basically `user_id` is `foreign key` referring `User` table

My insert code goes like this

```
exports.user = function(req,res){
var user_email = req.param('email', null);
var user_fname = req.param('fname', null);
var user_lname = req.param('lname', null);
var user_phone = req.param('phone', null);
var user_description = req.param('description',null);

var user_data = {
    table:TABLE_USER,
    data:{
        'email':user_email,
        'fname':user_fname,
        'lname':user_lname,
        'phone':user_phone,
        'description':user_description
    }
}

db.insert(user_data,function (result) {
      //How to get the ID of the last inserted row from result, 
      // get Id and insert in device table
      res.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
      res.write(result[0] + " ");
      res.end();    
    }
    );
}
```

Comment: What mysql driver/node module do you use?

Comment: I am using mysql "version": "2.6.2",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have a look at the documentation : [Getting the id of an inserted row](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#getting-the-id-of-an-inserted-row)

Their code example :

```
connection.query('INSERT INTO posts SET ?', {title: 'test'}, function(err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log(result.insertId);
});
```